Setting Up Network Lab for Router using Virtual Box 7
I am trying to experiment creating a router using Ubuntu Server using Virtual Box 7. Some tutorial I saw used Host-Only Adapter but it's marked as deprecated. I need to find more recent solution.
So I created 2 Virtual Box instance using Ubuntu Server for the router experiment, and Ubuntu Desktop to simulate the end-user.
I also created a Host-Only Network with the below configuration.

In the Ubuntu Server, I added 2 Network Adapter. Adapter 1 using the Bridged Adapter, and Adapter 2 using the Host-Only Network attached to the Network above.


In the Ubuntu Desktop I created only 1 Network adapter connected to the same Host-Only Network above.

Here are the screenshot of both of the instances. Is it the right configuration yet? How do I test & know if those are connected? Because I tried to ping the IP address there, but it returns Unreachable Network.



If you are trying to set up a VM (instead of the VM host) as router, you can/should use internal network for the LAN part (unless you want the VM host to also be in the LAN), especially if host-only were really deprecated. As per the screenshot, your router VM's LAN interface isn't up and configured on the guest side.

@TomYan thanks for the comment. It seems I misplaced the image. I just fixed the image. What do you mean the VM's LAN interface isn't up?
